# same fish and bash command for detecting python executable name

Tags: bash, shell, fish

Within a Makefile I need to check whether `python2` command exists and, if not, try with just `python`. Currently it works for bash/sh as follows:

```
PYTHON?=$(type -p python2 || echo python)
```

(and then using `$(PYTHON)` within make tasks).

However it fails when using fish shell because it does not support `||` (but instead requires using `or`, which does not work in bash/sh):

```
foo@bar ~> echo $(type -p python2 || echo python)

Unsupported use of '||'. In fish, please use 'COMMAND; or COMMAND'.
fish: echo $(type -p python2 || echo python)
                              ^
```

I can not figure out any approach that works for both bash/sh and fish. Any help please?

Comment: Does make actually drop to the user's default shell, or does it drop to sh?

Comment: Indeed it drops to /bin/sh by default unless SHELL variable is set:

Answer (score 2):

> I can not figure out any approach that works for both bash/sh and fish. Any help please?

If you *really* need to do this in both fish and bash, you'll have to use an external script that runs in one of the two.

However, being mostly unfamiliar with Makefiles, I have no idea why this needs to run in fish *and* bash - are you using "the user's shell"? That's usually a mistake, because that could be anything (even things like python!). For your code, you'll always want to specify the interpreter it needs - if it runs in /bin/sh, use that, if it needs bash, use that. If it's ruby, use that.

Comment: Well, this is not a script but a Makefile (a text file interpreted by the `make` command). And it exists in a software I provide to others. I just cannot mandate a specific shell to just run `make`.

Comment: Yes, you can. You'll need to mandate e.g. /bin/sh, and that won't actually be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, invalid. There were two issues, but were unrelated. In fact `make` uses  `/bin/sh` (unless `SHELL` variable is defined in the Makefile) to run like-shell commands within the Makefile itself.

It was failing due to another unrelated problem, sorry for the noise.

BTW:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL. If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell.